# .net navigation menu manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I am trying to have a menu with the different link pages, based on a user's role.
Using a master page with a asp:menu navigationMenu which is created with just one link, then based on a user's role mode links are added.

```
Menu menu = masterPage.FindControl("NavigationMenu") as Menu;

MenuItemCollection menuItems = menu.Items;

MenuItem menuItem;

switch (role)
{
    case "Level 1":          
         break;
    case "Level 2":
         menuItem = new MenuItem("Auditing", "", "", "~/Auditing.aspx");
         menuItems.Add(menuItem);
         menuItem = new MenuItem("Team Manager", "", "", "~/TeamManager.aspx");
         menuItems.Add(menuItem);
         break;
}
```

This only works for the current page. If a link is clicked on the menu then that new page only has one link that the master page ads at runtime.
Is there a way to actually update the "navigationMenu" `asp:menu` values so that they are persistent throughout the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a sitemap with SecurityTrimmingEnabled = "true" is a good solution.

Two other alternatives to consider are:

- Move the code to build the menu into the Master Page.
- Create a base class (`public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page`) and inherit all your pages from that base class.  Put the code to build the menu into the base class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider using `sitemap` with asp.net menu. If you set `securityTrimmingEnabled="true"` it should be able to automatically show/ hide menu items based on the roles.

[This link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/26/asp-net-menu-and-sitemap-security-trimming-plus-a-trick-for-when-your-menu-and-security-don-t-match-up.aspx) would give an idea

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that but I am using NetSqlAzMan for the role management so I'm not sure how easy that is to implement with the above.